# How do I assign an array to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code

```
export default class Application extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.config = config;
    this.data = {
      planets: [planetData]
    };

    this.init();

    let url;
    let count;
    let planetData = []
    let promises = [];

    //turn through the pages
    for (let p = 1; p < 7; p++) {
      url = `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${p}`;

      //fetch data
      promises.push(fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

          //push data to array
          for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            planetData = planetData.concat(data.results[i]);
          }

        }));
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(planetData.length, '=>', planetData);
      })
  }
```

I need help assigning the *planetData* array to *this.data{}*. I tried the following `this.data{ planets: [planetData]`, but it gave an error "Cannot access 'planetData' before initialization", which was expected. My syntax is also probably wrong, but I'm really new to JS.

Comment: Some additional thoughts. Keep the constructor as lean as possible. For public data which has to be fetched asynchronous provide prototypal methods. One also could write a factory which utilizes the leanest possible constructor and in addition takes care of each instance' initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the variable *after* the `planetData` array has been populated.

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```js
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(planetData.length, '=>', planetData);
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.data.planets = planetData;
    })
```

Comment: OP didn't ask to copy the array? They just said assign the array. The problem in their code is that they used a variable before it was defined. It's true that it's way more readable if you assign it from the then handler, at which point the variable has already been initialized.

Comment: You are right. I removed the part about copying the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `planetData` to the key `planets` later in your code using:

```js
this.data.planets = planetData;
```